# Google Data Studio - can I use Bubble Chart to show totals for fixed combinations of X and Y (not statistics but values)

Tags: google-data-studio, google-data-studio-charts

So I have a list of items that have Impact and Urgency parameters. These parameters all have a value of 1, 2 or 3.

I'd like to visualize a grid that shows the amount of items for each combination of Impact and Urgency, so my X and Y will range from 0 to 3.

However the issue is that the chart requires **statistics** on X and Y, so instead of grouping per value it calculates totals/averages/counts/..., which of course ruins the visualization.

*(Furthermore, the dimension that I need to select is basically useless, because I just want the bubble size to indicate the amount of records. I have the feeling Bubble Chart isn't what I need, except that I don't know other charts to visualize in a similar fashion. But I can work around this.)*